# when uploading files with this code the file is uploaded broken when tryting to upload files to azure devops

Tags: python, azure-devops, python-requests

[image: broken image]

[image: broken docs]

iam trying to upload attachments to azuredevops but the files are broken ,not sure why

```
attachment_file = BytesIO(requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000'+attachment.attachment.url).content)
                           
files = {"file": (attachment.attachment_name,attachment_file)}

response_attachment =requests.post(attachment_url,files=files,headers={'Accept': 'application/json',"Content-Type": "application/octet-stream",},auth=HTTPBasicAuth(azure_username,azure_token))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to upload attachment to Azure DevOps API correctly (0kb result)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53539831/unable-to-upload-attachment-to-azure-devops-api-correctly-0kb-result)

Comment: No the size is same as the original file

Comment: i have added screen shots for files how they appears , i think its related to `io.bytes`

Answer (score 0):

please try to convert that `BytesIO` object into readable format by using attachment_file`.read()`
Try the below code it could helps you.

```py
attachment_file = io.BytesIO(requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000'+attachment.attachment.url).content)
                           
files = {"file": (attachment.attachment_name,attachment_file.read())}

response_attachment =requests.post(attachment_url,files=files,headers={'Accept': 'application/json',"Content-Type": "application/octet-stream",},auth=HTTPBasicAuth(azure_username,azure_token))
```

Check here for more [info](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/get-post-requests-using-python/)

Comment: Thanks for your response i have the same error again , the file is uploaded but is corrupted not sure why

Comment: @tamdo, Are you using Image file ?

Comment: yes , all files are corrupted

Comment: Please have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31077366/pil-cannot-identify-image-file-for-io-bytesio-object) to save image file using BytesIO.